# Bind one mouse button to another

Tags: xorg, mouse, gui

The my middle mouse button is not particularly responsive, and I have several completely unused side buttons, and would prefer to map one of those to be interpreted as the middle button.

There are plenty of questions here about mapping buttons to keyboard sequences and window events, but nothing about how to make one button be interpreted as a different mouse button. (I don't need to SWAP buttons, I just want to map one over the other).

Comment: good question! I was looking in gconf, but nothing to be found...

Answer (score 0):

I found this though, surely could be of help:

[ManyButtonsMouseHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManyButtonsMouseHowto)

Good luck!